# HTML iframe inclusion

Tags: html, iframe, streaming

I am including an external URL to HTML file, the URL has online streaming where the streaming is working fine, but when i embed it in my html it lost the streaming.

URL : http://www.eboundservices.com:8888/iframe/connect/iframe.php?app=khybernews&stream=khybernews&screen=khybernews

How it be possible to make it possible to be embeded.

Comment: Why don't you ask them?  It seems to me they don't want you including their content in your website.

Comment: Yeah, they don't provide the facility, but is it possible? the port changed automatically when we include in our document.

Comment: They might have anti-iframe scripts/etc in place to keep you from stealing their content.  So no, I would say it isn't possible.